# can Cache Objects be nested php?

Tags: php, html, caching

I have code, which i want to run, this takes a few mins so I have a loading window, when the loading is complete the results are shown and the window is hidden. I want to cache all the results in a separate file and then redirect to the file.  I use ob_start, however i don't want to cache my code for loading window.  so can i open another ob start before the loading page code and then just delete it after with ob_end_clean, and then still get the rest of the contents at the end of the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: the documentation about ob buffering in php clearly states that the buffers can be stacked.

Comment: yes was just double checking as I have done t his , but it is not working, so wanted to rule this out.  THanks